# django date filter doesn't update

Tags: python, django, datetime, filter

I made a listview in a django project.
But when day go away, filter stay on starting data (start or refresh of web-server). Why it doesn't update every day?

this is my code: (table booking for restaurant)

models.py:

```
class Table_book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TIMES)
    people = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=TABLES)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
class List_book(ListView):
    model = Table_book
    template_name = 'list_today.html'
    queryset = Table_book.objects.all().filter(date=timezone.now()).order_by('date', 'time')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', login_required(List_book.as_view(), login_url='/login/'), name='home'),
```

in template.html the list objects populate a table.

Comment: The query is constructed at module loading time as class definitions are module level code.  `timezone.now()` is evaluated then. The queryset is evaluated at every call to the view but the query is built only once.

Comment: Can I solve creating a function(request) in main class?

Comment: That's not necessary. Django's default views provide the necessary runtime hooks. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make that query evaluate `now()` at runtime, you should override `get_queryset` instead of setting the static class attribute `queryset`:

```
class List_book(ListView):
    # ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Table_book.objects.all().filter(date=timezone.now()).order_by('date', 'time')
```

Comment: same issue...I see orders from yesterday

Comment: Update: It worked with datetime.time.today() function in date filter, maybe for my model type field.